# Cannot find module with tag 'sfml'

Tags: android, android-ndk, sfml

I think I soon will have to develop an application for Android, and I wanted to try the different stuff that one could use to do it. I know that SFML is making (or made ?) a portage for Android, but I have troubles to build the [example on the github](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/tree/master/examples/android).

I cloned the repo just to have all the files of the example on my computer, and when I type `ndk-build` at the root of the example (`SFML/examples/android`), this happens

```
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'sfml' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
jni/Android.mk:18: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

It seems like it doesn't search anywhere because my `NDK_MODULE_PATH` is not set correctly.

I am under ArchLinux and I installed the NDK using `yaourt -S android-ndk`.

I tried different `NDK_MODULE_PATH` but I don't know how to make it work.

Have you any idea of how to solve this ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Building-SFML-for-Android ?

Comment: Yes, my `PATH` seems correct, and my `ANDROID_NDK` is `/opt/android-ndk`. However, in this link, they explain how to build the SFML for android, but not how to build an android app written with SFML. And they don't speak about `NDK_MODULE_PATH`... do you have other ideas ? And thanks for taking time to post a comment.

Comment: Also get familiar with http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/compile-with-cmake.php When SFML is built, if `SFML_BUILD_EXAMPLES` is true then the examples are built.

Comment: Ok, I'll see that. thank you !

Comment: @Hiura thank you for you tips... I tried again the first link you gave me, and I managed to compile the SFML example app. If you post an answer on this thread, I'll set your answer as the answer of the problem. Thank you again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experimental support of Android in SFML 2.2 and its examples can be build using `cmake` and `make` as described on [this wiki page](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Building-SFML-for-Android).

To enable SFML samples, the `SFML_BUILD_EXAMPLES` flag has to be set to `TRUE` when configuring `cmake`. More build settings are available and presented in the [official cmake tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/compile-with-cmake.php) on SFML website.